# Allow users from different collection see a different stream

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have an Orders collection. It contains a field called venueId. And I'm querying against this field using `isEqualTo`. The venueId is the firebase user uid.  I also have a venues collection. It contains this venueId and also has a list of VenueAdmins ids(These ids are also firebase user uids )The app is a point of sales app(pos). I need to query the orders collections so that valueAdmins and venueId see the correct stream. Is quite easy to query with venueId.. `venueId,isEqualto, uid`. I'm wondering what's the best approach to allow the venueAdmins see the stream as well.

```
|-Orders   // collection
    order.   //doc
     venueId:'2344567788999999' 


|-Venues   // collection
    venue.   //doc
     venueAdmin: ['3333333333333','55555555555555555']
     venueId:'2344567788999999'
```

My query builder so far:  `queryBuilder: (query) => query.where('venue.id', isEqualTo: uid)`

Comment: It's not clear to me what the problem is here.

Comment: if venueAdmin 3333333333333 logs in,  how would it be possible for him to see the stream of orders. He is not the venueId, how can I query the stream so he can see the correct orders

Comment: I don't see how it matters which user is signed in.  As long as your security rules allow it, your users should be able to query the documents they need to be able to read.  If you have a query that's not working the way you expect, please edit the question to show that code.

Comment: I suppose the user matters because I'm querying with that value. With the above query the logged in user will see the filtered stream. Because his uid isEqualTo:venueId. I looking for a way for the admins to see the stream as well

Comment: Are you actually asking how to filter venues in a query based on values in the venueAdmin list field?

Comment: sorry I'm obviously unclear. Filter orders with venueAdmin. They're in different collections ..suppose that's my problem. The uid I can get easily...ieThe venueId. The adminValues are in another collection

Comment: Maybe you could you edit the question to make that more clear?  Right now, it looks like venueAdmin is a venue document field with list of strings.

Comment: venueAdmin are a list of strings(uids for what it's worth). I want to use these values to query in the orders collection. So venueAdmin will see the same stream as venueId. Because

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore does not have the capability to "join" documents from different collections in a single query.  A single query can only consider documents in single collection at a time.  The way you have your data structured now, it will require at least two queries.  First, to find a venue, then second, to find the orders for an admin in a venue.

The only way to make this easier from the perspective of queries is to denormalize your data by duplicating venue data into the order documents.  If each order also had a list of admins, then you could reduce this down to a single query.